# Name for the thing attached to spokes to remove tires?

Tags: tire, spokes, terminology

Some properties:

1. it is good to have it plastic so it won't break the inner tire
2. it is size is about 10cm*2cm*0.5cm at maximum, a small thing
3. you will attach them to spokes so you can change tire
4. you usually need them two pcs

Since I miss it, I work with spoons to remove tires but I really need the item. So I am just looking for the word of the tool to buy them from Ebay or some other shop online.

*Please, create a label 'definition question' or equivalent.*

Comment: Perhaps the terminology tag is the one you were looking for?

Comment: Agreed plastic on the outside, but metal cores are good if you have tight tires, otherwise cheaper plastic ones will snap in half and then you're SOL.

Comment: Chinasaur: What is "SOL", lost? How do you know you have tight tires? Where can you get tyre levers as plastic-outside-and-metal-cores?

Comment: "SOL" means "Sh*t Out of Luck", as in you are in a very bad situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tyre lever (in the UK anyway - WP redirects that to [tire iron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_iron) but to me that sounds more like metal fatigue. After all, they're not made of iron).

Comment: Same name in the states, with the American spelling for Tire :)

Comment: And the wrong pronunciation of "lever"

Answer (score 6):

There is now an entry in the [Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/) for [tire levers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1960#1960).

Comment: Not really an answer; this is more of a comment. (Nice entry in the index, BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

Yep.  Tire levers in the U.S.  Pedro's are the best.

Answer (score 0):

I actually call these devices, tire irons, but I have also heard them called tire levers.  Don't use a screwdriver!

Comment: Remember when you were a kid and you used spoons - then got told off when you bent them ?